# Laravel - Is there a way one would create a Laravel project via composer without php-json

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

I am trying to install laravel on my `Ubuntu 16.10`. I have installed composer via terminal (`sudo apt-get install composer`). I also have my `PHP7.0` already installed including all its dependencies (php-json inclusive). When I run "`composer create-project "laravel/laravel" project-name`", I get the following errors

"PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Composer\Json\json_decode() in /usr/share/php/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php:266
Stack trace:

> ## 0 /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php(664): Composer\Json\JsonFile::parseJson('{"packages":[],...',
>
> 'https://packagi...')"

when I run 'php -m', my php-json is missing on the php modules that have been enabled, even though it is already installed. During my research on this, I read something on [licencing issues](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63520) between the developers of php and json.

Is there a successful way of creating laravel projects using composer without php-json module?

Comment: hey @Yokonia try to download composer.phar and put that in where you wanna install project and run `php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel project-name`

Comment: umhm interesting, now its saying    [    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Phar' not found in /home/tazho/public_html/composer.phar:23
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/tazho/public_html/composer.phar on line 23    ] @Vishal

Answer (score 0):

The command must go like -

```
composer create-project "laravel/laravel" project-name
```

Comment: noted but that command requires a functional php-json module. Is there a work-around-it method?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve that issue when I upgraded my distro to `Ubuntu 17.04`. For some reason, the upgrading process just added everything together.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-json
```

You may also have your php cli version configured differently. Check with

```
php -v
```

If it is not 7.0 then do:
sudo apt-get install phpX.X-json

Next is to verify that the json extension is enabled. It should be located in /etc/php/X.X/cli/conf.d/ with {number}-json.ini

If it is not located in there, do the following while in that directory

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php/X.X/mods-available/json.ini 20-json.ini
```

Comment: the version of php is 7.0 and running sudo apt-get install php7.0-json says the newest version of php7.0-json is already installed. My php for some reason is not integrating my php-json

Comment: Can you verify that your cli is running on php7 by doing php -v? Then go to /etc/php/X.X/conf.d/ and see if there is json.ini file in there. It may have a prefix, for example mine says 20-json.ini

Comment: answer sounds good but as he told  php-json, if not you got it dude!!

Comment: my /etc/php/7.0/ only has these folders (apache2,  cgi,  cli,  fpm,  mods-available). There is no conf.d folder. Do I create it or maybe its in another directory? @Peravo

Comment: Oops! It should be the cli folder. I updated my answer as well